# Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) 404 Page not found error when calling action

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have started from the [ZF2 Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). I have a module called `Application`. Inside that module I have added my own `ShopController`. It is registered in the `module.config.php` which looks like this.

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'shop' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/shop[/][:action][/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                                    'controller'    => 'Shop',
                                    'action'        => 'index',
                            ),
                            'child_routes' => array(
                                    'default' => array(
                                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                    ),
                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Shop' => 'Application\Controller\ShopController',
        ),
    ),
    [... service_manager,translator,view_manager as in skeleton app ...]
);
```

I can reach the shop controller's index action by browsing to my.example.com/shop/ but when I try to reach a different action, e.g. my.example.com/shop/add it doesn't work. I get a 404.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am newbie as well in zend but in your ShopController class do you have method addAction which returns a view or an empty array()

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out and yes, it's there. :)

Comment: and add.phtml in the view directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding may_terminate = true and it was working, also removing the child_routes do work.

```
 'shop' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/shop[/][:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Shop',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true, // I added this
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have defined the child routes in the wrong place.